# Getting errors when I try to group by CTEs

Tags: sql-server

I would like to do a group by on object_name on my last cte in this query but I get the following error :

```
Column 'CTE1.TimesExecuted' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 85 Column 'CTE1.CountExec' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

[image]

```
WITH CTE1 AS(
    select  Object_name
            , max(Date_of_Object_Analysis) as MaxDate
            ,count(Object_name) as CountExec
            ,min(Date_of_Object_Analysis) as MinDate
            , SUM([Number_Times_Executed]) AS TimesExecuted 
            from
    _Admin_Database_Objects_Analysis_Tbl
    --where Object_Name = '_Admin_Client_Bing_GeoCordinates_Tbl'
    Group by Object_name
    )
    ,
    CTE2 AS (
            SELECT c1.Object_name 
            ,cast(c1.CountExec as int)*cast(c1.CountExec as int ) as CountMultiplied
            ,c1.CountExec+c1.CountExec+c1.CountExec+c1.CountExec as Addedup
            FROM _Admin_Database_Objects_Analysis_Tbl c2
            iNNER join CTE1 c1
            on c1.Object_name= c2.Object_Name

    ),
    --select * from CTE2 

    CTE3 AS (

        SELECT c3.Object_name 

            --,c2.CountMultiplied/c1.CountExec as Final_result
            --,c2.CountMultiplied
            ,c1.TimesExecuted/c1.CountExec as New_new_result
            --,c2.Addedup
            ,c1.MinDate
            FROM _Admin_Database_Objects_Analysis_Tbl c3
            INNER join CTE2 c2
            on c3.Object_name= c2.Object_Name
            INNER JOIN CTE1 c1
            on c3.Object_Name = c1.Object_Name
    Group by c3.Object_name 

    )select * from CTE3
```

Comment: You can avoid last `select * from CTE3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first CTE you grouped by Object_Name and all of the other entries were contained within an aggregate.  In your last CTE that isn't the case.

```
    SELECT c3.Object_name 
        ,c1.TimesExecuted/c1.CountExec as New_new_result
        ,c1.MinDate
```

I've removed the commented lines for clarity, but you'll notice that none of these are contained within an aggregate. (`MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`, etc).  If you want to group by `c3.Object_name` you'll need to put something around the other fields.  For example:

```
    SELECT c3.Object_name 
        ,SUM(c1.TimesExecuted/c1.CountExec) as New_new_result
        ,MIN(c1.MinDate)
```

Comment: Thanks ,I forget that every time that you need to put in some sort of aggregate to group by everytime

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems pretty straightforward. Basically what you are trying to do is:

```
select x, y from t group by x
```

Assume the following data:

```
insert into t (x,y) values (1,1),(1,2);
```

What should be returned by the query, (1,1) or (1,2) or something else?

SQL92 dictates that you need a full group by for every column in the select clause (aggregates excluded). SQL99 loosens that restriction and only requires that every column in the select clause must be functionally dependent of the group by clause. I'm not sure what version SQL-Server uses, if it is the latter one the error may be due to that it cannot determine the functional dependencies.

If you know that c3.Object_name, c1.TimesExecuted/c1.CountExec ,c1.MinDate is functionally dependent of c3.Object_name you can add any aggregate function to get rid of the problem:

```
SELECT c3.Object_name 
     , max(c1.TimesExecuted/c1.CountExec) as New_new_result
     , max(c1.MinDate) as mindate
FROM _Admin_Database_Objects_Analysis_Tbl c3
INNER join CTE2 c2
    on c3.Object_name= c2.Object_Name
INNER JOIN CTE1 c1
    on c3.Object_Name = c1.Object_Name
Group by c3.Object_name;
```

In case it is not functionally dependent, you need to figure out what values to choose for the group.